# How to remove load of Image processing from Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-processing, asp.net-web-api, imagemagick

We have 20 different websites which are on two servers on AWS. All websites are using a web application called DesignMaker (MVC application using ImageMagick to do image composition and alterations) to do heavy image processing for users images. Users can upload images to that application and start to do some design with their uploaded images. you can assume that all the image processing is optimized in the code.

My concerns here is to remove load of heavy image process from Cpu of the main servers and put it on another server. So the first things that comes to my mind is to separate that application and convert it to a web service that runs on other servers. In this way we put the load of image processing on other machines. Please tell me if I have missed something.

Is calling an API to do some image processing a good approach?

What are other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You're right to move image processing from your web thread, this is just bad practice.

If this was me (and I have done this in a few projects I've worked on) I would upload the image from the MVC app to a AWS S3 container then fire off a message using SQS or some queuing platform. Then have an Elastic Beanstalk instance listening for messages on the queue, when it gets the message it then picks up the images from S3 and processes it however you want.

(I'm an Azure guy so forgive me if I've picked the wrong AWS services, but the pattern is the same)